# DOI in biblatex's AIP citation style - just the number?

Tags: biblatex, doi, biblatex-phys

I use `\usepackage[style=phys,doi=true,eprint=true,biblabel=brackets]{biblatex}` to implement the AIP citation style with minor changes (showing DOI, using brackets instead of superscript, show arXiv by using `eprinttype=arXiv`).

Now I've noticed that the DOI is given like

> Author John, "Johns text",. Johns Journal 11, 10-12 (2020)
> 10.1119/1.123456

(meaning without the mention, that this number is a doi).

The arXiv is given as

> Author John, "Johns Text", 2013, arXiv:1234.5678

I was wondering if (in the AIP style) it is correct to NOT display e.g.

"DOI: 1234..."

and if so, how one could make this happen (since it might be confusing when I do so for arXiv but not for DOI).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strictly speaking the question of how DOIs should be displayed is off-topic here. But as far as I can see in published papers, the AIP does not show the DOI at all. Instead the journal name is linked to the DOI. (See e.g. https://aip.scitation.org/doi/pdf/10.1063/5.0076244. In the HTML version of the paper https://aip.scitation.org/doi/10.1063/5.0076244 the bibliography has the full DOI link).

If you want the DOI prefix, you can add it as follows

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=phys, doi=true]{biblatex}

\DeclareFieldFormat{doi}{%
  \mkbibacro{DOI}\addcolon\space
  \ifhyperref
    {\href{https://doi.org/#1}{\nolinkurl{#1}}}
    {\nolinkurl{#1}}}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: E. Sigfridsson and U. Ryde, ‘Comparison of methods for deriving atomic charges from the electrostatic potential and moments’, Journal of Computational Chemistry 19, 377–395 (1998) doi: 10.1002/(SICI)1096- 987X(199803)19 4<377::AID-JCC1>3.0.CO;2-P.]

If you want to mimic the HTML version of the bibliography, something like

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=phys, doi=true]{biblatex}

\DeclareFieldFormat{doi}{%
  \url{https://doi.org/#1}}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: E. Sigfridsson and U. Ryde, ‘Comparison of methods for deriving atomic charges from the electrostatic potential and moments’, Journal of Computational Chemistry 19, 377–395 (1998) https://doi.org/10.1002/(SICI)1096-987X(199803)19:4<377::AID-JCC1>3.0.CO;2-P.]

might work